# Solving task with probability

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve this task but I can't find solution at the moment.Task is:

Only two international airlines fly daily into an airport. UN Air has 70 flights a day and IS Air has 65 flights
a day. Passengers flying with UN Air have an 18% probability of losing their luggage and passengers flying
with IS Air have a 23% probability of losing their luggage. You overhear someone in the airport complain
about her luggage being lost. Find the probability that she travelled with IS Air.

So can anybody help me how to solve this?

Comment: Does each passenger have a piece of luggage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a conditional probability problem, your question can be rephrased to "Find the probability that she traveled with IS Air given that she lost her luggage"

We should use one form [Bayes' formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Conditioning_on_an_event) since someone losing their luggage can occur in two different ways (either traveling in the first plane or the other)

$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)\cdot P(A)}{P(B|A)\cdot P(A)+P(B|C)\cdot P(C)}$

Where $P(A|B)$ means the probability that event $A$ happens given that event $B$ has already happened

Here we have the following:

Event A: She traveled with IS Air, here we have $P(A)=\frac{65}{135}$ since we have $65+70=135$ flights a day and $65$ of them are with IS Air

Event B: She lost her luggage, probability someone loses their luggage is the following

Event C: She flew with UN Air which would be $\frac{70}{135}$

Can you continue? I advise you to do so alone as you would get used to applying the formula however, if we continue we get the following:

$\frac{0.23\cdot\frac{65}{135}}{0.18 \cdot \frac{70}{135}+0.23 \cdot\frac{65}{135}}=\frac{299}{551}=0.543$